# Simple text-based grid games in Python

Tags: python

So, I want to create a very simple top-down game in python. I have a very simple grid.

```
import sys

ROWS=5
COLUMNS=5

def display(grid):
    for r in range (0,ROWS,1):
        for c in range (0,COLUMNS,1):
            sys.stdout.write(grid[r][c])
    print()

def initialize():
    grid=[]
    for r in range (0,ROWS,1):
        grid.append([])
    grid[0]=['#','#','O','#','#']
    grid[1]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    grid[2]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    grid[3]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    grid[4]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
return(grid)

def main():
    grid=initialize()
    display(grid)

main()
```

O is the player. Now, All I want is to create a simple function that will first ask the user for the direction (2, for down, 8 for up, 4 for left, 6 for right) and then move the O on the grid. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Use `input()` to catch the user's response on the `main()` loop. On each input the user gives you just move the `O` through the multidimensional list.

Comment: Here are some hints: `input` (or `raw_input` if this is Python 2.x) can get a string from the user. You will probably want to keep track of the current position, maybe in `x` and `y` variables, but if you really don't want to, you can search each `grid` row for the column with `O` in it by using `'O' in row`.

Comment: I've figured out how to get directions, yeah. I just have no idea how to implement movement. I do know that I need to implement some sort of coordinates, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
# all your top-level setup code here

def initialize():
    grid=[]
    for r in range (0,ROWS,1):
        grid.append([])
    grid[0]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    grid[1]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    grid[2]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    grid[3]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    grid[4]=['#','#',' ','#','#']
    row, col = 0, 2
    grid[row][col] = '0'
    return grid, row, col

def move(grid, oldrow, oldcol, newrol, newcol):
    grid[oldrow][oldcol] = ' '
    grid[newrol][newcol] = 'O'

def main():
    grid, row, col = initialize()
    while True:
        display(grid)
        dir = input("Which way? ")
        if dir == '2':
            # move up, make sure to handle errors
        elif dir == '4':
            # move left
        # ditto for 6 and 8
        else:
            print("That's not a direction. Try 2, 4, 6, or 8.")
```

Just fill in the commented parts.

The way I implemented `move`, the user will leave a trail of blank spaces behind him. If you want to remember the original value that was there before he stepped there (`#` or ), you'll want one more variable for that.

Comment: This works! Well, almost. I managed to move, but I have problem with Walls '#'. Just wondering, should I implement wall condition to the move() function or main()?

Comment: What's the problem with walls? What do you want it to do? What is it doing now? Anyway, whatever logic it is you want to add, I'd probably add it to `move`—you can have it `raise` an exception for an illegal move, or make it return `newrow, newcol` for a valid move and `oldrow, oldcol` for an illegal one (and have `main` remember those values), etc. That means if you later added, say, an AI maze solver, it could use the same `move` function that `main` uses.

Comment: @user2961792: You might even want to pass the direction to `move`. (Maybe pass it as a `drow, dcol` pair, like `(-1, 0)` to move up, and `(0, 1)` to move right. That would allow you to add diagonal movement later, or a "run" mode that tries to move 3 spaces but stops if it hits a wall before then, etc.)