# Simple text-based grid game in Python-vol.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I [had a question about simple text-based grid python game yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275414/simple-text-based-grid-games-in-python) and some of you kind folks helped me out. I've figured out how to do movements and figured out how to prevent the player from moving through the walls. My `move()` and `main()` functions look like this:

```
def move(grid,row,col,nRow,nCol):
    grid[nRow][nCol]='O'
    grid[row][col]=' '
    if grid[nRow][nCol]==grid[row][col]:
        grid[nRow][nCol]='O'

def main():
    grid,row,col=initialize()
    while True:
        display(grid)
        dir=int(input("Where you wanna go?: "))
        if dir==2:
            nRow=row+1
            nCol=col
            if grid[nRow][nCol]=='#':
                nRow=row
                nCol=col
                print("There's a wall!")
            move(grid,row,col,nRow,nCol)
        row=nRow
        col=nCol

main()
```

The problem is that I have wall condition in my `main()` function, but I'd like to move it to `move()`. However, should I do that, player will simply move through the walls. So, how can I move wall condition to the `move()` while preserving functionality?

I tried to do it this way:

```
def move(grid,row,col,nRow,nCol):
    if grid[nRow][nCol]=='#':
        nRow=row
        nCol=col
        print("There's a wall!")
    grid[nRow][nCol]='O'
    grid[row][col]=' '
    if grid[nRow][nCol]==grid[row][col]:
        grid[nRow][nCol]='O'



def main():

    grid,row,col=initialize()
    while True:
        display(grid)

        dir=int(input("Where you wanna go?: "))
        if dir==2:
            nRow=row+1
            nCol=col
            move(grid,row,col,nRow,nCol)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are checking if there is a wall in your `main` function; how do you feel with doing this check inside `move` function? Do you think that your call to `move` would contain all necessary parameters?

---

**Edit**

I understand why your code is not working: `move` is a *method*, in the sense that it performs something on its parameters but returns nothing.

As `grid` is mutable, you can change its value in-place, *but that's not the case* for `row`, `col`, `nRow`, `nCol`: their values can be changed within `move` scope, but these changes will not be visible by `main`. This implies that `move` refusal of invalid moves is not visible from `main`, and the latter would only have trial values for `nRow` and `nCol`, not the updated ones.

A way to circumvent this would simply be to return `nRow` and `nCol`:

```
def move(grid, ...):
    (...)
    return nRow, nCol
```

And make `main` aware of this:

```
def main():
    (...)
        nRow, nCol = move(grid,row,col,nRow,nCol)
    row=nRow
    col=nCol
```

This way, `move` can update values of `nRow` and `nCol` in `main`.

---

Another solution, as given in a comment by **abarnet** in [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275414/simple-text-based-grid-games-in-python), would be that `move` would raise an `Exception` when there would be a wall:

```
class MoveException(BaseException):
     """exception to be raised when move would hit a wall"""
     pass

def move(grid, row, col, nRow, nCol):
    if grid[nRow][nCol]=='#':
        # illegal move!
        raise MoveException
    else:
        # move can be done, updating grid content
        grid[nRow][nCol] = '0'  # moving character
        grid[row][col] = ' '    # cleaning grid

def main()
    grid,row,col=initialize()
    while True:
        display(grid)

        dir=int(input("Where you wanna go?: "))
        if dir==2:
            nRow=row+1
            nCol=col
        # specify other possible movements here

        # now trying to move
        try:
            move(grid,row,col,nRow,nCol)
        except MoveException:
            # illegal move! 
            # We do not update character's position.
            # This could also be the place to print some error message
            # but I'm lazy and will let you add something here ;)
            pass                    
        else:
            # move could be performed, updating character's position
            row, col = nRow, nCol
```

How are you feeling with this "try and handle problems" solution? I feel it as more readable, and raise of exception can pass several layers of methods, which makes them very useful.

---

By the way, it seems to me that your move method misses a conditional block `else`, that would make it a little bit cleaner:

```
def move(grid,row,col,nRow,nCol):
    if grid[nRow][nCol]=='#':
        # this block is executed if there is a wall in the desired position
        nRow=row
        nCol=col
        print("There's a wall!")
    else:  
        # this block is only executed if there is no wall in the desired position
        grid[nRow][nCol]='O'  # moving character's character
        grid[row][col]=' '    # emptying previous position
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I want to move wall checking to the move() function, so that my main() function won't have too much unnecessary stuff. I just don't know how, I don't know what I'm missing. Wall checking condition works like a charm while in main(), but completely ignores its role if I try to implement it in move()

Comment: Could you update your question with your `move` content, so that we can have a look at your try?

Comment: Updated, maybe it'll help